# Split SQL Function , Calculate string length b/w 2nd and 7 commas

Tags: sql, sql-server

⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠Suppose that I have string having comma between them and I want to find the length of string between 2nd to 7th comma or (n to n+).

I am using this steps.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split_1]
(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(MAX), -- List of delimited items
    @sDelimiter VARCHAR(5) = ',' -- Delimiter that separates items
) 
RETURNS @List TABLE (id int,item VARCHAR(8000))
BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
Declare @Count int 
SET @Count =1 
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT
    @sItem = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList, 1, CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) - 1))),
    @sInputList = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList, CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) + LEN(@sDelimiter), LEN(@sInputList))))
    IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List SELECT @Count ,@sItem
            SET @Count =@Count +1 
    END
    IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List SELECT @Count ,@sInputList -- Put the last item in
  SET @Count =@Count +1 
    RETURN
END

Select sum(len(item))+(7-2)as'LengthOfChar(b/w 2 and 7 comma)','abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv' as'String'
from [fn_split_1]('abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv',',') where Id<7 and id>2
```

**Input and Output Result**

```
Inputs String is                 : 'abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv'
String between 2nd and 7th comma : 'efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs'
LengthOfChar(b/w 2 and 7 comma)   : 19 
The result from the function  would be 
    ID      Values
    1       abc
    2       def
    3       efg
    4       hij
    5       lkm
    6       nop
    7       qrs
    8       tuv
```

But we cann't ignore the commas between the text.
Is there more optimized ways to achieve this?

Comment: One solution is to *try* to *avoid* string splitting by converting source string to XML and then by using XQuery string-length and sum functions.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow there is one solution based on XML & XQuery:

```
DECLARE @Source NVARCHAR(100) = N'abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv'
DECLARE @Start  INT = 2
DECLARE @End    INT = 7

-- Solution #1
SELECT
    (CONVERT(XML, N'<root><i>' + REPLACE(@Source, N',', N'</i><i>') +  N'</i></root>'))
    .query(N'for $t in (root/i[position() gt sql:variable("@Start") and position() le sql:variable("@End")]/text()) 
        return <len>{string-length($t)}</len>')
    .value('sum(len)', 'INT') + (@End - @Start - 1)
```

**[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=dbaf68290b0df76a9e135dd4324afcf0)**

Edit 1: Replaced `...query('...').query('sum(len)').value('.', 'INT')` with `...query('...').value('sum(len)', 'INT')`

Note: The assumption is that source string doesn't contain XML reserved chars (ex. `<`). Let me know if this is your case.

Comment: XQuery: `gt` means `greater than` / `>`, `le` means `less of equal` / `<=`

Comment: Very impressive +1

Answer (score 2):

First it pains me to see loops in split/parse functions.

That said, this alternative will also return the sequence number

**Example**

Declare @YourTable table (String varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv')

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select Value = sum(len(RetVal)+1)-1
                From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.String,',')
                Where RetSeq between 2 and (7-1)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
String                           Value
abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv  19
```

**The UDF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

**Just for fun**

```
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv',',')
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       abc
2       def
3       efg
4       hij
5       lkm
6       nop
7       qrs
8       tuv
```

Comment: I am not able to understand the CTE(S) (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1) what's this doing, though it's pretty easier to understand the loop, I am not sure which of the function would be faster. If you can help me understand. It will be new thing from me to explore and know about.

Comment: the count which I am expecting is 19.

Comment: @RohitKumar Just a little logic switch to include/exclude commas.  See Updated.  Also, the tally table approach is DRAMATICALLY faster than the loops, especially if you need to parse an entier column.   I was amazed at the differance on a 25,000 row sample.

Comment: little logic switch to include/exclude commas. To Exclude Value = sum(len(RetVal)+1)-1 and to Include Value = sum(len(RetVal)+1)+1 please let me know if I am right.

Comment: @RohitKumar  Correct.  From what I undstand, you want to include the commas in the count less the initial.  Also, you may notice that I changed the range to (7-1) so that we exclude the 7th item

Comment: Sorry I missed noticing the other change,  thanks for briefing it and the example too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to split?  You could find the position of each 'Nth' character and get the difference.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.NthCharIndex
(
@CharToFind varchar(8000), 
@StringToSearch varchar(8000), 
@N int
)

RETURNS int

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @pos int, @ctr int, @ret int

    SET @pos = 0
    SET @ctr = 0

    BEGIN 

        WHILE(@ctr < @N)
        BEGIN

            SELECT @ret = CHARINDEX(@CharToFind, @StringToSearch, @pos + 1)

            SET @ctr = @ctr + 1

            SET @pos = @ret

        END

    END

RETURN(@ret)

END

GO
```

Then you'd just need to find the difference.

```
Select  dbo.nthCharIndex('a', 'bananaBanana', 6) - dbo.nthCharIndex('a', 'bananaBanana', 1)
```

Comment: The query is straight forward but using Select  dbo.nthCharIndex(',', 'abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv', 6) 
- dbo.nthCharIndex(',', 'abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv', 1) is returning 20 instead of 19.

Comment: @greenpark, sorry I replaced bananaBanana with my string.

Comment: True, the difference in the starting position of both the 1st and 6th commas in this example is 20.  If you want the length between, then you also have to subtract the length of that first delimiter ... in this case 1 since it's just one character.  So we end up with "dbo.nthCharIndex(',', 'abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv', 6) - dbo.nthCharIndex(',', 'abc,def,efg,hij,lkm,nop,qrs,tuv', 1) - 1"